# PHP How to make a variable increase after reload

Tags: php

What I want to do is to have a variable that increments by 1 after every reload. Now, I can't do cookies because I want it to increment globally, and I've tried sessions but I had no luck with them. If anyone could help me out I'd really appreciate it. I actually can't give any code samples because my tries have turned out very messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a variable for each user, then I would definitely go with sessions :

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) {
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;
} else {
    $_SESSION['counter']++;
}
```

However if you want a unique variable that increases at each load (i.e the same for all users), then you could use a file to store the number of views :

```
<?php
if(file_exists('counter.txt'))
{
        $counter_f = fopen('counter.txt', 'r+');
        $count = fgets($counter_f);
}
else
{
        $counter_f = fopen('counter.txt', 'a+');
        $count = 0;
}
$count++;
fseek($counter_f, 0);
fputs($counter_f, $count);
fclose($counter_f); 
?>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking about! Thank you!